# How do you find the values of a and b that makes the function continuous?

Tags: calculus

How do you find the values of $a$ and $b$ that makes the function continuous?

$f(x) = a x^2 - 1$ for $x<1$, $2$ for $x=1$, $2/bx$ for $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take the limit from the left and from the right and make them equal

Comment: Here "make them equal" means make them equal to each other and to the value of the function at the point in question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, You are right